# Will not increment according to modulus

Tags: c#

I'm trying to increment the number of headers based on the page click by the user. But it seems I cannot get the proper results. (The number of headers should also increment.)

I just want to have 1 header only on page 2, 2 headers in page 3, and so on.

Trying to get a result like this :

```
Clicked page : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
no of headers: 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7  8  9
```

Here is my code :

```
var page = 3; //example only
var api = page;

if (page % 5 != 2)
{
    api -= 1;
}
else 
{
    api++;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain a little more. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: ??? what a strange question

Comment: api = page + (page % 5 ==1 ? 0 :-1) -page/6 ;

Comment: @Graffito omg that gives the correct answer. sorry for the bother but can you explain it to me how did you get that equation? please. i dont kinda get it

Comment: The first part "page + (page % 5 ==1 ? 0 :-1)" was quite obvious for pages 1 to 5. I then realized that for pages above 6, a correction factor was necessary because every 6 pages you only add 5 headers.

Comment: @Graffito ohh okay thank you!!